# mat-card click is not getting the value of checkbox

Tags: angular, typescript

[Database array of roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnGHo.png)

I added a checkbox inside a mat-card. On Checkbox click, I am getting the value of checkbox. But when I am adding the click event on the mat-card, the checkbox gets checked but does not gives me any value. And I am storing the value of checkbox in an array.

I tried this. Basically I have to get roles in an array.

Click function on mat card `(click)="Roles()"`.

```
<mat-card (click)="Roles()" [ngStyle]="{'background': admin? 'rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.5)':'bottom'}" class="role-card" class="card-style" style="background: bottom">
      <img mat-card-image src="../assets/admin_logo.png">
      <mat-checkbox class="checkboxStyle" [(ngModel)]="admin" color='primary' (change)="onRoleChange($event)" value="admin" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
      </mat-checkbox>
</mat-card>


Roles(){
  this.admin = !this.admin;
  return false
}

onRoleChange(event) {
  const roles = <FormArray>this.roleFormGroup.get('roles') as FormArray;
  if(event.checked) {
    roles.push(new FormControl(event.source.value))
  } else {
    const i = roles.controls.findIndex(x => x.value === event.source.value);
    roles.removeAt(i);
  }
}
```

I am not getting error messages, just on mat-card click I am unable to get the value of the checkbox.

On `onRoleChange` trigger is basically an event trigger on checkbox.

Comment: Could you provide a `stackblitz` with an example? As phrased currently, it's hard to understand the issue.

Comment: okay let me do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I tried it and got a solution of it.
Here is the solution.

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxlayout.sm="column" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayoutGap="10px">

                    <mat-card [ngStyle]="{'background': admin? 'rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.5)':'bottom'}" class="role-card" class="card-style" style="background: bottom">
                      <img mat-card-image src="../assets/admin_logo.png">
                      <mat-checkbox class="checkboxStyle" [(ngModel)]="admin" color='primary' (change)="onRoleChange($event)" value="admin" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></mat-checkbox>
                    </mat-card>

                    <mat-card [ngStyle]="{'background': employee? 'rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.5)':'bottom'}" class="role-card" class="card-style" style="background: bottom">
                        <img mat-card-image src="../assets/employee_logo.png">
                        <mat-checkbox class="checkboxStyle" [(ngModel)]="employee" color='primary'  (change)="onRoleChange($event)" value="employee" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></mat-checkbox>
                    </mat-card>

                    <mat-card [ngStyle]="{'background': customer? 'rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.5)':'bottom'}" class="role-card"  class="card-style" style="background: bottom">
                        <img mat-card-image src="../assets/customer_logo.png">
                        <mat-checkbox class="checkboxStyle" [(ngModel)]="customer" color='primary'  (change)="onRoleChange($event)" value="customer" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></mat-checkbox>
                    </mat-card>
                </div>
```

And in the TS file i wrote a function and a RoleChange Event

```
onRoleChange(event) {
      console.log('on role change');
      const roles = <FormArray>this.roleFormGroup.get('roles') as FormArray;
      if(event.checked) {
        roles.push(new FormControl(event.source.value));
      } else {
        const i = roles.controls.findIndex(x => x.value === event.source.value);
        roles.removeAt(i);
      }
    }

    selectRole(val){
      console.log('on select change');
      const roles = <FormArray>this.roleFormGroup.get('roles') as FormArray;
      if(val == 'admin'){
        this.admin =! this.admin;
        if(this.admin)
          roles.push(new FormControl(val))
      }else if(val == 'employee'){
        this.employee =! this.employee;
        if(this.employee)
         roles.push(new FormControl(val))
      }else{
        this.customer =! this.customer;
        if(this.customer)
          roles.push(new FormControl(val))
      }

    }
```

Simply click on matcard checks the checkbox as gets the value in form array.